# $(\sqrt{10}+3)^{2010}$

Tags: number-theory

What are the first 100 digits of $(\sqrt{10}+3)^{2010}$ after the decimal point?

I used a calculator to figure out $(\sqrt{10}+3)^{2}$ up to of $(\sqrt{10}+3)^{6}$ and they all have increasing numbers of nines after the decimal point. Does that pattern continue, and if so, why?

Comment: Hint: show for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n := (3 + \sqrt{10})^n + (3 - \sqrt{10})^n$ is an integer - and further hint for that, find a recurrence relation satisfied by $a_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a = 3 + \sqrt{10}$ and $b = 3 - \sqrt{10}$.  Note that $ab = 3^2 - 10 = -1$.  Now $a^n + b^n$ is a positive integer, in fact $c_n = a^n + b^n$ satisfies the recurrence $c(n) = 6 c(n-1) + c(n-2)$ because $a^n$ and $b^n$ do,
with initial conditions $c(0)=2$, $c(1) = 6$. Thus 
$$ a^{2010} = c(2010) - b^{2010}$$
where $c(2010)$ is a large positive integer while $b^{2010}$ is a small positive number.  In fact $|b| < 10^{-0.7897}$, so $b^{2010} < 10^{-1587}$, i.e.
$a^{2010}$ has at least $1587$ nines after the decimal point.

Comment: You gave it all away!

Answer (score 3):

When $a, b, n$ are positive whole numbers we have the following sum of conjugate quadratic surds

$(a+\sqrt{b})^n+(a-\sqrt{b})^n$=exactly a whole number

There are several ways to prove this. One way is to expand both powers with the binomial theorem.  When you add them together, the terms containing odd powers of $\sqrt{b}$ cancel out and the terms containing even powers of $\sqrt{b}$ which are whole numbers doubled up (so the sum is actually an *even* whole number).

Here with $a=3,b=10,n=2010$ the conjugate term $(a-\sqrt{b})^n$ is very small  (because the base is absolutely much smaller than $1$ and the exponent is large) and positive (because the exponent is even).  You are to check whether it's so small that the other term in the sum, which is what you want, has to have 100 or more nines after the decimal point to complete a whole number sum.

Comment: Why does $(a+\sqrt b)^n+(a+\sqrt b)^n$ always an integer? Can you please edit your answer to prove this fact?

Comment: You don't know that?  Methinks you should have, for this question.

Comment: Thanks for that. Methinks that if I had known that, I would not have had to post it on MSE. :)